"Read External Storage Permissions" Error while trying to classify a audio in flutter using tflite_audio
I'm trying to build a audio classification app in flutter. I'm running the code as is this page. Except for fetching the audio from a file instead of mic. When I try to run that I'm getting this Error.
Tested it on multiple devices. Android 12, 13 and 14. Same error persists.

Everything worked fine when I ran it in iOS. And In the android things worked as excepted when using mic. But when I try to classify on a file, the error popped up.
I gave all the permissions required for reading and writing in the storage by adding these lines in the android manifest.
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" /> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

I tried giving the permissions using the flutter permission_handler module too, and nothing changed.
